# listener message on port 23

Tags: tcp, socket, telnet, socat

I want to have a message to anyone that tries to telnet (port 23) to my server that they are connecting to the wrong port, then disconnects them.

Basically something like socat would be ideal, but I couldn't get it working. Needs to be a persistent service (forks), so it goes back to wait on port 23 after executing.

I thought something like:

```
sudo socat -u tcp-l:23,fork gopen:/home/ajross/message.txt
```

...but this doesn't display anything.

Comment: What operating system and version?   Hardware ?  While this is not a direct answer, I would be tempted to put an entry in iptables (if your OS supports it) to REJECT packets to port 23.  Most OS will display "Connection refused" in response to this, however it is NOT customizable on the server end and you won't be able to tell them what the correct port is if that is your intention.  Article on how to do this: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/iptables-block-port/

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I am using Linux/Ubuntu Server 18.04. The message needs to inform the user of which port to connect to, so blocking the port isn't going to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

One approach using `netcat`:

```
while true; do nc -l -p 23 < /home/ajross/message.txt; done
```

This will run an infinite loop, using `netcat` listen for incoming connections, and spit out the contents of `message.txt` to anyone connecting (test with `nc localhost 23`).

Comment: Yes, I considered netcat too, and whilst the above works to an extent, it doesn't seem to terminate the connection, so the user is forced to kill it ungracefully (probably via closing their telnet app, or semi-gracefully with a Ctrl+]. Is there any way to get it just to drop connection on EOF?